How to get the current locale in nextjs app router like in getServerSideProps?
I am working on a nextjs 13 project where I transform it from v13 to v14.
The project uses the "pages" directory for pages and now I am trying to move the project to the app router. For this I will move/create the pages inside the "app" directory.
All the pages in pages directory are now using getServerSideProps to get the data from a server.
Now it seems that it is not possible to use getServerSideProps in the app router. With GetServerSideProps it was possible to get the current locale. But how can I get the current locale now?
//src/pages/somepage.tsx

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
  props: {
    ...await serverSideTranslations(locale as string, ['common', 'header']),
  },
})

How can I make it now work without getServerSideProps? How can I get the current locale?
//src/app/somepage/page.tsx

const getContent = async function(lang: string){
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?lang=' + lang);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

export default async function Page() {
    const locale = "...."; //how to get the locale?
    const data = await getContent('de');
    return "TEST!!! " + data.title;
}

Any ideas how to do this?

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#routing-overview

@cmgchess thanks. Yea I saw that page but the middleware examples didn't work. But on that page on the bottom there is a link to a repository with a proper example. Which seems to work: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/app-dir-i18n-routing
The problem is that nextjs does not support localized routing in the app directory.
